# Double hashing - probe count probabilities

Tags: hash, hash-tables

From TAoCP, Vol. 3 by Knuth we know that *expected (mean)* probe counts for hash tables with open adressing and double hashing collision-resolution are:

- $1 \over 1 - \alpha$ - for unsuccessful search
- ${1 \over \alpha} ln({1 \over 1 - \alpha})$ - for succesful search

Where $\alpha$ is load factor.

Are there expressions for *probabilities* of making exactly $i$ = 1,2,3,.. probes?

Comment: He derives the expectations for uniform probing from the probabilities just a few pages later.  I have second edition (1998), and the derivation starts on pg 534 under the section titled "Analysis of the algorithms."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Wandering Logic](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/7459/wandering-logic) noted, there are approximate expressions for probabilities of probe count in *unsuccessful* search  case in TAoCP, a few pages later expressions for expected probe count:

$1-\alpha$, $\alpha(1-\alpha)$, $\alpha^2(1-\alpha)$, ... - probabilities of making 1, 2, 3, ... probes respectively.

In *successful* search case I derived approx. expressions myself, relying on explanation of expected probe count formula in the book:

$1 - {\alpha\over2}$, ${\alpha\over2} - {\alpha^2\over3}$, ${\alpha^2\over3} - {\alpha^3\over4}$, ...